# Using recursion to backtrack on a grid

Tags: java

i'll keep this concise. My problem is I generate a grid of dxd squares. In ever square on the grid there contains a random integer from 1 - (d-1). And there is one square containing a 0 (the goal). I randomly start on any square that is not the goal and I can move in ANY direction the amount of spaces of the square that I'm currently on (can't go out of bounds) and I need to use recursion to solve this problem. It also may be impossible to reach the goal with where I started and the layout of the grid.

I tried playing around with different algorithms and stumbled upon DFS, with what I have now, i'm not sure how to properly "backtrack" and avoid staying in an infinite loop. For instance if i start on a square with value 3, I'll move right 3 and if the square I moved to is 3 and I cant move right because its out of bounds so i'll go back left, then right, then left and so on.

```
if(finalArray[startPosX][startPosY] == 0) {
    System.out.println("we did it!");
    return true;
}
else {
    if(((startPosY + squareValue) <= boardSize-1))
        MovePlayer(startPosX, startPosY + squareValue); //Move right
        
    if(((startPosY - squareValue) >= 0))
        MovePlayer(startPosX, startPosY - squareValue); //Move left
        
    if(((startPosX + squareValue) <= boardSize-1))
        MovePlayer(startPosX + squareValue, startPosY); //Move down
        
    if(((startPosX - squareValue) >= 0))
        MovePlayer(startPosX - squareValue, startPosY); //Move up
}
```

This is my recursive method that will end up going in an infinite loop, I'd like some guidance with how to properly be able to not get stuck in a loop. How can I keep track of the previous square I was on and not go in the direction that will cause it to loop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check the base case/ boundary case in recursive function?

Comment: This is a classic rat in a maze problem. What you are doing is correct but you are missing the crux of backtracking algorithms. When you take a certain path and it fails, you need to return false in the end, so that your algorithm takes a different route.

Comment: You forgot to check the result returned from `MovePlayer` invocation everytime, should be `if(MovePlayer(startPosX - squareValue, startPosY))return true;`

Comment: The reason you are in infinite loop is that your algorithm repeatedly visits the same square, say if you start on a square with value 3, then you move right to  another square with value 3 too, then you will move back to the first square with value 3 again by moving left. you can mark the square as visited by setting the value to -1, when you recurse back, change the value back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things that need to be done to fix your algorithm:

1. everytime you start walking into one path, you need to check the returned value to see if you have reached the goal, if you have, just return true, no need to try other paths (but if you want to find all possible paths, keep trying the rest paths).
2. mark the square as visited by converting it's value to be negative (or you can create a new array, for example, `visitedArray`, to mark visited squares if you don't want to or are not allowed to change the original array) to avoid going into infiniate loop:

```
if(finalArray[startPosX][startPosY] == 0) {
    System.out.println("we did it!");
    return true;
}
else {
    
    //already visited
    if(visitedArray[startPosX][startPosY]) return false;
 
    //mark this square as visited
    visitedArray[startPosX][startPosY] = true;

    boolean find = false;
    
    if(((startPosY + squareValue) <= boardSize-1))
        if(MovePlayer(startPosX, startPosY + squareValue)) find = true; //Move right, if goal can be reached, end recursion.
        
    if((!find && (startPosY - squareValue) >= 0))
        if(MovePlayer(startPosX, startPosY - squareValue)) find = true; //Move left
        
    if((!find && (startPosX + squareValue) <= boardSize-1))
        if(MovePlayer(startPosX + squareValue, startPosY)) find = true; //Move down
        
    if((!find && (startPosX - squareValue) >= 0))
        if(MovePlayer(startPosX - squareValue, startPosY)) find = true; //Move up

    //mark the square as unvisited, but to improve performance, 
    // you can delete this.
    visitedArray[startPosX][startPosY] = false;

    return find;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, i tried to change the value of every index I've been to by turning it into a negative number, but then if I need to restart from that point I cant go to that point. Like lets say I start at 3 and 3 under my starting value theres a zero, but my algorithm will try right first, when it goes right it will change my start to -1 and it will never go back to that to try the down path

Comment: Yes you will definitely try the down path, **but you don't have to go back to do that** 
after you try right first, see the code in answer, `if(visitedArray[startPosX][startPosY]) return false;`, it only checks if current square is visited at the beginning **before** trying four directions one by one, when you convert it into a negative number it will not stop you from trying the down path. So you don't have to go back, the `recursion` itself will take care that. think of recursion as data structure `stack`, the down path is pushed into stack, and will be popped out after finish right first

Comment: And that you say `it will never go back to that try the down path` is exactly the reason you get into infinite loop, converting the square to -1 is to **avoid** going back. In computer world, when you invoke function2 from function1,  function1 is not finished untill function2 returns, so function1 will be saved into stack and will be popped out and resumed after function2 returns. function1 and function2 can be the same function, and that's recursion.

Comment: I tried your method with creating an empty array and keeping track of where I started and it seems to work fine, thank you for the feedback you've left

Comment: Glad I have helped, for algorithms like recursion, the more you think and try, the easier they become, happy coding.